# Using JS how can I stop child Iframes from redirecting or at least prompt users about the redirect

Tags: javascript, iframe, redirect

Many sites have scripts similar to the one below. These are put to stop other people from framing the sites.

```
if (top.location != location) {
  top.location.href = document.location.href;
}
```

I need some way to realize that the iframe is trying to redirect, and if it is , I will remove the iFrame and instead place a link to the site. This way, I don't violate the usage policy of the framed website and also link to the site. I understand you can use the onbeforeunload event as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/752465/preventing-child-iframe-from-breaking-out-of-frame) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/958997/frame-buster-buster-buster-code-needed) but both seem really unethical. I remember reading somewhere about a library that does the exact same thing (digg does the same thing). Any leads?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The problem with the above solution is that it can be removed using a simple:

```
if( top != self )
    delete top.onbeforeunload;
```

Once that has been called, then the `prevent_bust` will never be incremented, and that means that the website will be freely re-directed without your consent or knowledge.  Bad deal.

If you wanted a consistently functional version of that solution, I would recommend doing this instead:

```
// Create a random seed value, making it almost impossible to 
// determine what is being tested for.
var prevent_bust = Math.random() * 3000; 

// enclose everything in a function, so that it cannot be addressed
function iniFunc ( init ) { 
    // The function is no longer in scope of the main window.
    function onbeforeunload() { prevent_bust++ }
    window.onbeforeunload = onbeforeunload;
    setInterval( function() {
        // make sure the function was not deleted.
        if( window.onbeforeunload != onbeforeunload )
        {
            prevent_bust = init + 1;
            window.onbeforeunload = onbeforeunload;
        }
        if (prevent_bust > init ) {  // All comparison is to the random seed.
            prevent_bust -= 2
            window.top.location = 'http://server-which-responds-with-204.com/' 
            // Unfortunately, you have absolutely no idea which website caused
            // the incrementation, so you cannot replace it with a link!
            //
            // You might try to simply ignore it and just use the iframe as is -- 
            // theoretically, they are no longer able to bust this frame. 
            // (this theory will be disproved below).
       }
   }, 1 );
};
iniFunc( prevent_bust );
```

Unfortunately, this does cause leave one problem -- it is a trivial thing to retrieve the interval which has been set, unset it, and then re-direct the page:

```
// setTimeout will return the highest timeout which is not "in use", in this case,
// it will be the original setInterval (from the above function) + 1.
// Event if there are 1,000 intervals already set, it will be rather trivial to 
// clear them all.
var currentInterval = 10000;
// window.setTimeout( gotoHREF, 100 );

// clearInterval will not interfere with setTimeout, so we can clear all
// of the Intervals already set.
for( var i = 0; i < currentInterval; i++ ) top.clearInterval( i );

function gotoHREF(){
    top.location.href = "http://<my-url/>";
}
```

Your best bet is actually to solve this issue server side (if you can).  If you have access to the server for the website which will hold iframes, create an interim, proxy location where you pull in the website's data and then strip the script tags:

```
// In php
$dd = new DOMDocument();
// file_get_contents will simply convert the entire web address into a String
$dd->loadXML( file_get_contents( "http://" . $_GET[ 'loadedURL' ] ) );
$scripts = $dd->getElementsByTagName( "script" );

// iterate through the website and remove all script tags.
for( $i = 0; $i < $scripts->length; $i++ )
{
    $current = $scripts->item( $i );
    $current->parentNode->removeChild( $current );
}

// output it to the dummy page.
echo $dd->saveXML();
```

You would then use the tag:

```
<iframe src="redirect.php?loadedURL=http://www.google.com"></iframe>
```

Unfortunately, this will mean that your iframe will be running without JavaScript which might cripple, if not completely lobotomize the website in question.  You'll also need to make sure that all of the src attributes are correctly modified for descendant nodes in the foreign site's HTML.

On the other hand, you could have your server check the framed site and all of its JS pages to see if the RegExp top(.|[\s*("|'))location (this will match top.location, top["location, and top[ 'location) exists (or if there are any references to top at all), and then use a link if it does exist and the site proper if it does not.  The detriment here is that then you are forcing the user to wait for the secondary site to load twice -- once on the server and once in their browser. (unless everything is done through JS, but that is generally more annoying, in my opinion).

Personally, I'm of the opinion that the "don't frame my site" crowd can generally win most battles which involves the iframe directly.  On the other hand, if code is used to process the HTML before it is appended to a web page, then the other side stands more than a fighting chance.




As a side note, all of these can be accomplished through JavaScript and AJAX, but that will generally be a bit slower.  Use the server, if you can.

Comment: The first option looks good. There is a problem though, a refresh pressed on the browser will trigger the window.onbeforeunload handler and perform the exact same action defined in function. Also, any action on the site, like a page request or a form submit doesn't go through as the handler is called again. The solution for this would be a rather painful "Add pre-submit/navigation javascript functions to nullify the actions from the frame buster script.

Comment: This doesn't stop somebody from using `<body onload="breakOutOfIframe()"> ... </body>`

Answer (score 6):

If you are using HTML5 I would suggest making use of the new "sandbox" property BUT it is not yet compatible with all the browsers. http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_iframe_sandbox.asp

In my case I just added "allow-forms" and "allow-scripts" as the sandbox property values and the embedded site no longer redirect and still can run JavaScript

using "allow-top-navigation" as value made the site redirect again!

ex: `<iframe sandbox="allow-forms allow-scripts" ... /></iframe>`

If anyone knows any Cons to using this approach I would love to know about it.

*Someone else with same answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9880360/1404129 (I ran into this answer later)*

Answer (score 3):

You can try to create frame buster buster, everything is described by Jeff Atwood in his blog post: [We Done Been ... Framed! - coddinghorror.com](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001277.html)

In short, you should implement something like this:

```
var prevent_bust = 0  
window.onbeforeunload = function() { prevent_bust++ }  
setInterval(function() {  
  if (prevent_bust > 0) {  
    prevent_bust -= 2
    window.top.location = 'http://server-which-responds-with-204.com' 
    // replace your iframe with link to it
  }  
}, 1)
```

Comment: Looks alright. Will have to write a little more js to perform all the other actions. Thanks!!