# LinkedIn auth request page in iFrame?

Tags: html, iframe, linkedin-api

Has anyone any experience with LinkedIn? I'm trying to put their auth request (the allow this application to access my...) page in an iFrame and load it into my page.

However, immediately after loading - it reloads itself into the entire window. Does anyone know if this is deliberately blocked... I thought it wasn't possible for the child iFrame to do such a thing?

Appears this is relevant [Using JS how can I stop child Iframes from redirecting or at least prompt users about the redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1794974/using-js-how-can-i-stop-child-iframes-from-redirecting-or-at-least-prompt-users-a) but this redirects to another page you request, no stops the iframe reloading.

Comment: So you are trying to install the LinkedIn 'Sign In' button on one page, and pull that through to another page via iFrame?

Answer (score 3):

We don't want you to do this. We want people to be able to see the URL in their browser, so they know it's not a phishing attempt. Otherwise, anyone could just create a fake page and redirect people to it.

Comment: Is this still true today? I notice that there is the X-FRAME-OPTIONS header in the browser which tries to prevent iFrame access.

Comment: Hello, is there anything like **"Invite Linkedin Connection"** now a day?